# How to make a single ring chart with Apache eCharts?

Tags: echarts

I'm trying to make a chart in Apache eCharts that is a single ring with a large number in the middle. I want to use it to display a website score.

This is the closest image example I can find online of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

And I have found these [polar bar charts](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/basics/release-note/5-2-0/#labels-for-polar-bar-charts) in the Apache eCharts docs which look great:

[image]

But I don't know how to only have one large ring with a number displayed in the middle.

Do you know how I can achieve that?

Here is my current code, [taken from the docs](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/basics/release-note/5-2-0/#labels-for-polar-bar-charts):

```JavaScript
option = {
  angleAxis: {
    show: false,
    max: 10
  },
  radiusAxis: {
    show: false,
    type: 'category',
    data: ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
  },
  polar: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      data: [3, 4, 5, 6],
      colorBy: 'data',
      roundCap: true,
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'start',
        formatter: '{b}'
      },
      coordinateSystem: 'polar'
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a variant of the Gauge chart.
here is a series that would create something very close to your first image example.

```
    series: [
        {
            type: 'gauge',
            startAngle: 90,
            endAngle: 270,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,

            progress: {
                show: true,
                width: 18
            },
            pointer: {
                show: false
            },
            axisLine: {
                show: false
            },

            axisTick: {
                show: false
            },

            splitLine: {
                show: false
            },
            axisLabel: {
                show: false
            },

            title: {
                show: false
            },
            itemStyle: {
                color: 'blue'
            },
            detail: {
                formatter: '{value}',
                color: 'auto',
                offsetCenter: [0, '-0%'],
                valueAnimation: true,
               
            },
        }
    ]
```

[Here is a link to an example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-ring) that is similar to your second image